# Can a payout, using PayPal Payouts API, be funded directly from the associated Bank account instead of PayPal account?

Tags: paypal, braintree, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I have been building a marketplace application with an iOS app as front-end that drives the business. The app can accept payment either through a paypal account or a credit card. I have integrated Braintree iOS SDK into my app and linked the paypal business account in Braintree controlpanel. The funds processed using PayPal are being routed to the paypal and those processed using cards end up in the bank account linked with Braintree merchant.

Now, the core of the application is to take a certain commission and payout the rest to the sellers involved in transaction. I have taken the seller's PayPal ID at the time of registration to pay them.I have explored the PayPal docs and found that Payouts REST API does exactly what I need provided I maintain the required balance in the merchant account.This is where things came to a standstill. Specifically, I need to get confirmation on the below points

```
   1.As there are two different places(paypal merchant and bank account 
    linked to braintree) where my funds are parked, Is there any 
    possibility that the transaction could directly be funded from the 
    bank account if the same is linked to both merchant accounts? 
   2.Will PayPal withdraw the entire amount at once or in partial 
     transactions.
```

Can anyone who have been in a similar situation suggest how to go about paying out the sellers. I am open to any alternative that satisfies all the requirements of the app.